# Correct way to modify startup options for svc:/network/finger:default in Solaris 10?

Tags: security, solaris, sunos, smf, inetd

I want to make "finger" harmless on Solaris 10, and I see this in the man page;

```
OPTIONS
   fingerd supports the following option.
  -s    Enable secure mode. Deny forwarding of queries to other remote hosts.
```

Is it possible to change the start-up options for the in.fingerd without "cheating" and editing the manifest (/var/svc/manifest/network/finger.xml) itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the official way to modify an SMF of an inetd-managed service is with inetadm;

**Before**

```
inetadm -l svc:/network/finger:default | grep exec
         exec="/usr/sbin/in.fingerd"
```

**Fix**

```
inetadm -m svc:/network/finger:default exec="/usr/sbin/in.fingerd -s"
```

**After**

```
inetadm -l svc:/network/finger:default | grep exec
         exec="/usr/sbin/in.fingerd -s"
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should be able to change the **"start/exec"** property of a service with **svccfg** command:

```
svccfg -s FMRI setprop start/exec = astring: \"PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE COMMAND_LINE_OPTIONS\"
```

Then, refresh and restart the service:

```
svcadm refresh FMRI
svcadm restart FMRI
```

Comment: Found out that for an SMF using inetd, there is no "start/exec".
To view the command that starts the inetd-managed SMF, you have to run;
`svcprop -p inetd_start/exec svc:/network/finger:default`
Which shows `/usr/sbin/in.fingerd`.

I'm so close, I just keep getting a syntax error when I try to modify this...
`svccfg -s svc:/network/finger:default setprop inet_start/exec = astring: "/usr/sbin/in.fingerd -s"`

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out 'inetadm' is the only way to pull it off. 'svccfg' keeps throwing "Syntax Error".